# Change value in local storage object if id matches

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to change the text of a string inside an object that is inside the local storage when a button is clicked. I can get it working when there is only a single object in the local storage but if multiple objects are added, it always changes the last/most recent object with in the local storage, no matter which one you click (the buttons are linked to the objects ids) I'm guessing it's either the looping of the objects or the adding of them that is the issue, any ideas?

```
var bg = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bg'));

for (var i = 0; i < bg.length; i++) {
    if(bg[i].id == e) b[i].status = 'Closed';  
}

localStorage.setItem('bg', JSON.stringify(bg));
```

Comment: What's `b` in your code? What is `e`? If it's the clickevent object, you maybe want to use `e.target.id` instead. Did you try debugging your code to check for which items it is updating the status?

Comment: the b is meant to be bg, sorry and the e, yes it is. The code I showed is an the setStatus(e) function, which is using this event listener: closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => setStatus(id));

Comment: Please update the code in your question to reflect all the corrected typos and the whole function, including how it is triggered.

Comment: I fixed it, ended up having nothing to do with the setStatus function that I displayed here, thanks for taking the time.